# How to handle Multiple Clients on Single Thread Server (with Sockets)

Tags: c, performance, sockets, server, client

### Before I Start

**Please don't mark this question as a duplicate.**  I have already seen the numerous posts on SO about handling multiple clients with socket programming.  **Most people recommend just multi-threading**, but I am trying to avoid that path because I have read it has a few problems:

- Bad Scalability
- Large Overhead/Inefficient/Memory Hungry
- Difficult to Debug

Any posts that I have read that specifically talk about using a single thread either have bad/no answers or have unclear explanations, like people saying "Just use `select()`!"

---

### The Problem

I am writing code for a server to handle multiple (~1000) clients, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to create an efficient solution.  Right now I already have the code for my server that is able to handle 1 client at a time.  Both are written in C; the server is on Windows using WinSock and the client is on Linux. 
The server and client send several communications back and forth, using `send()` and blocking `recv()` calls.  Writing this code was pretty simple, and I won't post it here because it is pretty long and I doubt anyone will actually read through all of it.  Also the exact implementation is not important, I just want to talk about high level pseudocode.  The real difficulty is changing the server to handle multiple clients.

---

### What's Already Out There

I have found a nice PDF tutorial about how to create a WinSock server that handles multiple clients and it can be found here: [WinSock Multiple Client Support](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0M8Jl7L5zhsRUdWRVNYZ3pxdEk/view).  It's in C++ but it's easily transferable to C.

From what I understand the server operates something like this:

```
while (running) {
    Sleep(1000);
    /* Accept all incoming clients and add to clientArray. */

    for (client in clientArray) {
        /* Interact with client */

        if (recv(...) == "disconnect") {
            /* Disconnect from client */
        }
    }
}
/* Close all connections. */
```

The problem that I see with using this approach is that **you essentially only handle one client at a time (which is obvious because you aren't multithreading)**, but what if the interaction with each client only needs to happen once?  Meaning, what if I just want to send some data back and forth and close the connection? **This operation could take anywhere from 5 seconds to 5 minutes depending on the speed of the clients connection, so other clients would be blocking on a `connect()` call to the server while the server handles a client for 5 minutes.**  It doesn't seem very efficient, but maybe the best way would be to implement a waiting queue, where clients are connected and told to wait for a while?  I'm not sure, but it makes me curious about how large servers send out update downloads concurrently to thousands of clients, and if I should operate the same way.

Also, is there a reason for adding a `Sleep(1000)` call in the main server loop, if the `send()` and `recv()` between the server and client take a while (~1 minute)?

---

### What I'm Asking For

What I want is a solution to handling multiple clients on a single threaded server that is efficient enough for ~1000 clients.  If you tell me that the solution in the PDF is fine, that's good enough for me (maybe I'm just too preoccupied with efficiency.)

**Please give answers that include a verbal explanation of the implementation, server/client pseudocode, or even a small sample code for the server**, if you're feeling sadistic.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows-specific: I/O Completion Ports

Comment: Regarding your first bullet point, I have a very hard time believing that a single threaded solution will scale better than a multithreaded solution.  The instant you go multithreaded, you immediately scale up from one to the number of cores in your system.  If you're talking scalability and multiple thousands of clients, you're probably thinking in terms of servers like [this](https://www.thinkmate.com/systems/servers/rax/64-core).  On one of those, multithreading will get you close to a 64 to 1 performance improvement.

Comment: P.S. do **NOT** make the mistake that was made by the company I worked for a few years ago.  Their solution to scaling was to go single threaded and to spin up one server instance per core.  For a lot of reasons, this did not scale at all well.

Comment: I must concur with Alex. If your server is (a) Windows based, and (b) has no intention of ever deviating from (a), I/O completion ports are the cat's whiskers. Frankly, they're *incredible* and several answers on SO, as well as documented usage examples across the web, all try to communicate justice to just how omfg awesome they really are. Hitting up google for "io completion port examples" is worth a half hour of your time. You won't regret it; I promise.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look up I/O Completion Ports

Comment: The main difference between one-thread-per-client designs and single-thread, or other async/completion desings is where the state-machine is that handles the incoming data that arrives in various, mixed byte-arrays from all the clients.  If one-thread-per-client, the OS provides the state-machine.  If io-completion, or other such, the developer must provide it with user code.  Pick your poison carefully:)  Especially, you should think very carefully about statements like 'Difficult to Debug'.

Comment: lol, 'Just use select()' yes, and all such examples seem to be 'echo' servers whose data has no messaging structure, require no protocol state-machine and simply fire all byte-arrays back to where they came from:)

Answer (score 0):

I have written single thread socket pool handling. Im using non-blocking sockets and select call to handle all send, receive and errors.
My class keep all sockets in array, and build 3 fd set's for select call. When something happens it check read or write or error list and handle those events.
For example, non-blocking client socket during connection can trigger write or error event. If error event happens then connection failed. If write happens, connection is established. 
All sockets is in read fd set. If you create server socket (with bind and listen) new connection will trigger read event. Then check if socket is server socket then call accept for new connection. If read operation is triggered by regular socket then there is some bytes to read.. just call recv with buffer arge enough to suck all data from that socket.

```
SOCKET maxset=0;
fd_set rset, wset, eset;
FD_ZERO(&rset);
FD_ZERO(&wset);
FD_ZERO(&eset);

for (size_t i=0; i<readsockets.size(); i++)
{
    SOCKET s = readsockets[i]->s->GetSocket();
    FD_SET(s, &rset);
    if (s > maxset) maxset = s;
}
for (size_t i=0; i<writesockets.size(); i++)
{
    SOCKET s = writesockets[i]->s->GetSocket();
    FD_SET(s, &wset);
    if (s > maxset) maxset = s;
}
for (size_t i=0; i<errorsockets.size(); i++)
{
    SOCKET s = errorsockets[i]->s->GetSocket();
    FD_SET(s, &eset);
    if (s > maxset) maxset = s;
}


int ret = 0;
if (bBlocking)
    ret = select(maxset + 1, &rset, &wset, &eset, NULL/*&tv*/);
else
{
    timeval tv= {0, timeout*1000};
    ret = select(maxset + 1, &rset, &wset, &eset, &tv);
}

if (ret < 0)
{
    //int err = errno;
    NetworkCheckError();
    return false;
}
if (ret > 0) 
{
    // loop through eset and check each with FD_ISSET. if you find some socket it means connect failed
    // loop through wset and check each with FD_ISSET. If you find some socket check is there any pending connectin on that socket. If there is pending connection then that socket just got connected. Otherwise select just reported that some data has been sent and you can send more.
    // finally, loop through rset and check each with FD_ISSET. If you find some socket then check is this socket your server socket (bind and listen). If its server socket then this is signal new client want to connect.. just call accept and new connection is established. If this is not server socket, then just do recv on that socket to collect new data.
}
```

There is few more things to handle... All sockets must be in non-blocking mode. Each send or recv calls will return -1 (error) but error code is EWOULDBLOCK. Thats normal and ignore error. If recv returns 0 then this connection is dropped. If send return 0 bytes sent then internal buffer is full.
You need to write additional code to serialize and parse data. For example, after recv, message may not be complete (depending on message size) so it may take more than one recv calls to receive complete message. Sometimes if messages is short recv call can deliver several messages in buffer. So, you need to write good parser or design good protocol, easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding single-thread approach: I'd say it's bad idea because your server processing power is limited by performance of single processor core. But other than that it'll work to some extent.

Now about multiclient problem. I'd suggest using `WSASend` and `WSARecv` with their compilation routines. It also can be scaled to multiple threads if necessary.

Server core will look something like this:

```
struct SocketData {
    ::SOCKET socket;
    ::WSAOVERLAPPED overlapped;
    ::WSABUF bufferRef;
    char buf [1024];
    // other client-related data
    
    SocketData (void) {
        overlapped->hEvent = (HANDLE) this;
        bufferRef->buf = buf;
        bufferRef->len = sizeof (buf);
        // ...
        }
    };

void OnRecv (
    DWORD dwError,
    DWORD cbTransferred,
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
    DWORD dwFlags) {
    auto data = (SocketData*) lpOverlapped->hEvent;
    if (dwError || !cbTransferred) {
         ::closesocket (data->socket);
         delete data;
         return;
         }
    // process received data
    // ...
    }

// same for OnSend

void main (void) {
    // init and start async listener
    ::SOCKET serverSocket = ::socket (...);
    HANDLE hAccept = ::CreateEvent (nullptr, 0, 0, nullptr);
    ::WSAEventSelect (serverSocket, FD_ACCEPT, hAccept);
    ::bind (serverSocket, ...);
    ::listen (serverSocket, ...);
    // main loop
    for (;;) {
        int r = ::WaitForSingleObjectEx (hAccept, INFINITE, 1);
        if (r == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION)
             continue;
        // accept processing
        auto data = new SocketData ();
        data->socket = ::accept (serverSocket, ...);
        // detach new socket from hAccept event
        ::WSAEventSelect (data->socket, 0, nullptr);
        // recv first data from client
        ::WSARecv (
            data->socket,
            &data->bufferRef,
            1,
            nullptr,
            0,
            &data->overlapped,
            &OnRecv);
        }
    }
```

Key points:

- wait in main loop (`WaitForSingleObjectEx`, `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` etc.) must be alertable;
- most data processing done in `OnSend/OnRecv`;
- all processing must be done without blocking APIs in `OnSend/OnRecv`;
- for event-based processing events must be waited in main loop.

`OnRecv` will be called for each processed incoming packet. `OnSend` will be called for each processed outgoing packet. Keep in mind: how many data you asked to send/recv is not the same as what actually processed in packet.